# Why my webpages body content is not taken into account to display in google SERP?

Tags: seo, google-search, keywords, googlebot, google-index

It's confusing for me that I have content on my webpages, however, when I search with the `site:` operator it is not taken into account.

[image: Example search results]

There is something like **"Thank you for contacting us...."**

.....and when I tried to search within my site again with a `site:` search operator, now with the keyword "Mumbai Database", I thought the search would include the content of my article and highlight them, but instead it highlight some keywords from the menu.

I even checked the cached pages, it is showing that content (article) was there in the page.

1. Can somebody with similar experiences or knowledge explain me why it is happening?
2. Is it normal?
3. If not, how can I fix this?

[image: Example search results with keywords]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Q.** What is "content"?
**A.** Everything between the `<body>` tags. Not just the bit you call "content" at the bottom of the page.

The text "Thank you for contacting us..." is one of the first bits of textual content in the page source, and you don't have a meta description, so it can't be too much of a surprise that this text is appearing as the description when doing an empty `site:` search. (However, very few *real* users use a `site:` search when searching.)

Again, the keywords you list are included in the page navigation (many many times), which again is positioned high in the content in the source of the page. Try searching for something that actually appears in the article's content.

- Try positioning your actual content near the top of the page source (currently it is near the bottom of a very large page).

For example, the HTML source of your page currently looks something like this (#line number):

```
#003 <html>
#024 <head>
:        <!-- HEAD Section... -->
#082 </head>
:        <!-- A chunk of "CONTENT" between the HEAD and BODY sections!? -->
#191 <body>
:        <!-- Header - "CONTENT" -->
:        <!-- Navigation (much) - "CONTENT" -->
:        <!-- SCRIPT -->
:        <!-- Other common page elements - "CONTENT" -->
#700     <article>
:            <!-- Actual article "CONTENT" -->
#731     </article>
:        <!-- Mixed content -->
#980 </body>
#981 </html>
```

As you can see, your "actual content" - the content that you want Google to take notice of only starts at line#700. There are 500+ lines of other *indexable* "content" above it that contains the keywords you are searching on. The fact you have wrapped your actual page content in `<article>` tags isn't necessarily going to promote that content in the SERPs description. Content is content. (You also have 100 lines of "content" between your HEAD and BODY sections!?)

Your actual page content also appears a long way down the rendered page.

Comment: Thank you for answering me. Can you please emphasis on "Again, the keywords you list are included in the page navigation (many many times), which again is positioned high in the content in the source of the page" especially "which again is positioned high in the content in the source of the page" : What do you mean by that?

And 2nd : The positioning part : Do you mean positioning the catual content in UI or HTML. I mean by absolute, realtive positioning or UI?

Comment: I meant the content (article) is in <article> tag

Comment: I've updated my answer.